# Shell extension for drive like GDrive?

Tags: windows, shell-extensions

How can I go about with writing a shell extension to display online files in a virtual drive like the Gmail Drive does?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a two-part article on CodeProject that may contain the info to implement such an extension to explorer: [part 1](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/TipsInNSE_SubFld.aspx), [part 2](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/NSExtAddDelFld.aspx).